# Matching multiple items

Tags: java, machine-learning, e-commerce, nlp

I am running a e-commerce startup. I am currently facing a problem of matching multiple items as they are input from the sellers portal. I would ideally display one item when a user searches for the item and not display the same item multiple times (each from a different seller with a different details page/picture).

Similar to [this](http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B00008CM68/ref=dp_olp_new?ie=UTF8&condition=new)

As a part of this effort, I was thinking of using NLP to compare multiple item description page and to club them together. Can someone help me in pointing out algorithms or libraries that can match description content of multiple items from different sellers.?

We are using Java, so any APIs that you can suggest will be helpful!

Answer (score 2):

As someone researching in this area, I can only suggest you to read [Data Matching by Peter Christen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3642311636). It will guide you through the process of matching and goes through some techniques that can be used in general.

However, the whole problem is a bit more difficult as the generic approaches (inverted index and some similarity metric) don't perform very well. You will have a lot of false-positive matches in your dataset, which usually turns into a manual review process of matching candidates. As this is very costly, usually a classifier is used it distinguish between a good match and a not-so-good or wrong match. But as a startup you won't have a lot of training data to train such a supervised classifier here.

Here are a few quick-tips that I found very useful in my daily work:

- Expect a lot of garbage (accessory business is the largest in terms of products in e-commerce and will crap your matches)
- Normalize your data well, at best according to **your** database standards
- Use word-level models instead of character-level ones (e.g. a Bigram model)
- Use the product name and pricing information, all other attributes are usually huge garbage cans

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have normalized all my attributes and tried removing garbage.